# Slow upload speed into amazon s3 upload

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nestjs

I'm trying to upload 50gb data into s3 bucket using nestJs(nodeJs) and angular 13.
I have thousand of marriage images with row files and I'm uploading these file into s3 bucket but it's take more time to upload.

I also enable transfer-acceleration into s3 configuration and all files upload into multi-part data.

Angular process:

1. user select thousand of file using file input
2. after i called one api for each file for upload into loop. for example i have 5 files so it will call 5 api one by one.

Backend process:

1. file upload into multipart data (using multi-part upload)
2. after file upload into bucket I will store bucket data into database

any one tell me how can I improve uploading speed into s3 bucket ?

NestJs code

```
async create(request, photos) {
        try {
            let allPromises = [];

            photos.forEach(async (photo) => {
                let promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
                    let file = new ChangeFileName().changeName(photo);
                    this.s3fileUploadService.upload(file, `event-gallery-photos/${request.event_id}`).then(async (response: any) => {
                        console.log(response)
                        if (response.Location) {
                            await this.eventPhotoEntity.save({
                                studio_id: request.studio_id,
                                client_id: request.client_id,
                                event_id: request.event_id,
                                file_name: file.originalname,
                                original_name: file.userFileName,
                                file_size: file.size
                            });
                        }
                        resolve();
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        this.logger.error(`s3 file upload error : ${error.message}`);
                        reject();
                    })
                });
                allPromises.push(promise);
            });
            return Promise.all(allPromises).then(() => {
                return new ResponseFormatter(HttpStatus.OK, "Created successfully");
            }).catch(() => {
                return new ResponseFormatter(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Something went wrong", {});
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.logger.error(`event photo create : ${error.message}`);
            return new ResponseFormatter(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Something went wrong", {});
        }

    }
```

Upload function

```
async upload(file, bucket) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            bucket = 'photo-swipes/' + bucket
            const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // chunk size is set to 10MB
            const iterations = Math.ceil(file.buffer.length / chunkSize); // number of chunks to be broken

            let arr = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) {
                arr.push(i)
            }

            try {
                let uploadId: any = await this.startUpload(file, bucket);
                uploadId = uploadId.UploadId;
                const parts = await Promise.allSettled(
                    arr.map(async (item, index) => {
                        return await this.uploadPart(
                            file.originalname,
                            file.buffer.slice((item - 1) * chunkSize, item * chunkSize),
                            uploadId,
                            item,
                            bucket
                        )
                    })
                )

                const failedParts = parts
                    .filter((part) => part.status === "rejected")
                    .map((part: any) => part.reason);
                const succeededParts = parts
                    .filter((part) => part.status === "fulfilled")
                    .map((part: any) => part.value);

                let retriedParts = [];
                if (!failedParts.length) // if some parts got failed then retry
                    retriedParts = await Promise.all(
                        failedParts.map((item, index) => {
                            this.uploadPart(
                                file.originalname,
                                file.buffer.slice((item) * chunkSize, item * chunkSize),
                                uploadId,
                                item,
                                bucket
                            )
                        })
                    );

                const data = await this.completeUpload(
                    file.originalname,
                    uploadId,
                    succeededParts, // needs sorted array
                    bucket
                );
                resolve(data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err)
            }
        });
    }
```

Bandwidth

[image]

Comment: Is this a UX question, or a technical question? Because you didn't provide any statistics such as how long each file takes, but describe more on how the user selects the photos and how the application handles it. If it is UX question, for sure there are creative ways. E.g., user selects first, then uploads happen transparently after so user doesn't have to wait. If it is a technical question, what is your current speed and why do you think it is slow?

Comment: Im selecting 1676 files from input file and total size is 50GB and it take 3 hours to upload

Comment: 50 GB in 3 hours translates to 5 MB per second, or roughly 40 Mbit/sec. What is the bandwidth of your connection? If you don't know that, run one of the many Internet speed tests to find out. And if your bandwidth is _significantly_ higher than 40 Mbit (because there are always overheads), then edit this question to (1) provide these statistics, and (2) _show your code_. As it stands, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: i have added code please check now

Comment: Also added bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

This the typical issue of slowness when you upload many number of small files to s3 .
One large 50GB will be uploaded way faster than multiple small files of of total size 50 GB .

The best approach than can work for you to parallelize the upload and if you can use **AWS CLI that would be very fast with multiple parallel  connection .**

Multiple part upload is for single large file
Transfer acceleration is also not going to help much here

Comment: Aws cli is okay but how can I use cli into nodeJs because its command line

Comment: You can use this in Lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html .But best would be to use EC2 and run CLI from EC2

Comment: @Sudarshankumar That link has nothing to do with running the AWS CLI in a Lambda

Comment: @AnonCoward this is clearly explained here https://medium.com/@corymaklin/tutorial-amazon-web-services-part-3-lambda-functions-with-aws-cli-ba9f53c5f5ec